# Crash app by EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios

[image]My app was crash many time and fabric show this error 
Crashed: Thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000106275012

and line number 2313 
on that line , i assign one variable like
 NSMutableArray* marrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
i don't know why crash many time.

Raw Text

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192d3f4c8 (null) + 42824
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192ce6f08 (null) + 36944
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cde0c8 sqlite3_step + 528
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192caa90c sqlite3_exec + 468
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cbee08 (null) + 83664
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cbe990 (null) + 82520
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cf19f4 (null) + 14196
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cd12b4 (null) + 38352
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cd0ad8 (null) + 36340
9  libsqlite3.dylib               0x192d51688 (null) + 117000
10 libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cc9b20 (null) + 7740
11 libsqlite3.dylib               0x192caf67c (null) + 20292
12 libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cab9a4 (null) + 4716
13 libsqlite3.dylib               0x192cab1d0 (null) + 2712
14 libsqlite3.dylib               0x192caaf24 (null) + 2028
15                     0x10008b680 +[myModel selectQuery:QueryId:db:] (myModel.m:2313)
16                     0x10009935c +[myModel clockIn:isManual:type:MdicData:] (myModel.m:6197)
17 Foundation                     0x19329e2d8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19186d68c _pthread_body + 240
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19186d59c _pthread_body + 282
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19186acb4 thread_start + 4
```

Thanks

Comment: canyou add your stack trace

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No i used zombie also

Comment: ok can you add your fabric crash report

Comment: https://fabric.io/mlslogic/ios/apps/com.lotus.tek/issues/59b22600be077a4dcc49bcc7?time=last-seven-days  Fabric report

Comment: the error in inside the mymodel class inside selectquery method check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i already wrote crash  line in question, i saw line but i can't understand why crash

Comment: can you show the raw text

Comment: the memory released for the object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153925/discussion-between-bhadresh-sonani-and-anbu-karthik).